# What was the un-named French phrase in Joe Hart's Obscura?

Tags: plot-device

In Joe Hart's [Obscura](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/36440711-obscura), at two points when Dr. Gillian Ryan visits Dr. Eric Ander's office/dwelling, the narrative mentions a French phrase that is prominently visible.

> On the farthest wall was an immense flat screen that stretched from
>   floor to ceiling and at least twenty feet across. At the moment, a
>   scrawl of French was displayed there, the phrase somewhat familiar but
>   escaping her at the moment.<sup>1</sup>

and

> Inside the lights were low, the large sectional couches slabs of
>   shadow. The same phrase in French she'd seen the first time floated on
>   the main display.<sup>2</sup>

As far as I can tell it's never explicitly revealed what this French phrase said, nor are there any clearly marked indications as to its content. But it seems odd to have lampshaded it so heavily just to leave it dangling, and it *felt* like the kind of thing that I was meant to be able to intuit. Did I miss clues? **Is the reader supposed to know what this phrase was, and if so, what was it?**

<sup>1</sup> p. 174 in my Kindle version

<sup>2</sup> p. 240 ibid.

Comment: You don't think it's meant to create some dramatic tension that she might be starting to lose things?

Comment: @DavidW Good thought, but I don't think it adds up - there's no other mention that she speaks French (or used to), so there isn't really an implication that she should be able to read the phrase but now can't. Also, at the first instance it's a point in the dramatic arc where Dr Ryan is certain that she has a firm grip on what's been happening (even if others are less sure).

Comment: In case it _does_ reference a real quote, "Je pense, donc je suis" would be amusingly meta.  (Note that Descartes did originally write it in French.)

Comment: I was guessing A La Recherche du Temps Perdu, and was disappointed to reach the end without a reveal

Comment: I've twitted at the author. Hopefully he'll weigh in

Comment: @Valorum Great idea, thanks! Let us know if he replies